# Getting an error in Odoo 8 Products Form Template

Tags: odoo, odoo-8

I'm getting this error in Products Form template after editing privileges, but I don't know how to revert to a previus version.

Uncaught Error: Unknown field valuation in the domain ["&",["valuation","=","real_time"],["cost_method","in",["standard","average"]]]

http://domain.com:8069/web/js/web.assets_backend/a5efa52:3605

Any idea?

Comment: It's look like new field *"valuation"* is not present in *product_product* object. Upgrade your module properly and than check out in product form weather *"valuation"* is there or not? If there, than checkout it's value what it's take and compare with your domain value.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `Setting > Local Modules`

Search Module `stock_account` click on upgrade.

[image]